# google actions webhook promise await - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: promise, google-cloud-functions

I am struggling with getting JS to wait for a process to finish before continuing
With a simple wait, the process continues while it is meant to wait

````
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const app = conversation();


// wait ms milliseconds
function wait(ms) {
  console.log("in the wait");
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
}
  
async function getData() {
          console.log(`start wait `);
          await wait(5000);
          console.log(`end wait `);
}

app.handle('findit', conv => {
  console.log(`-----> handle activated `);
  console.log(`-----> BEFORE call getdata`); 
  getData();
  
  console.log(`--------END OF HANDLE ----------------------`);
 });

exports.ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);```

[Timing logs][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/96Ydv.png
````

Comment: What is the async task that you need to wait for?

Comment: The actual task I want to use is a mysql query but the issue was the task was still finishing but the program did not wait for it. So I end up with no data
I thought it was an issue with my process so I simplified it down to just a timing wait as per examples I found.
so in the code here, I am doing a simple timer, but as per the logs, the entire process finishes at 10:39:46  and then shows the end wait at 10:39:51.

My confusion is I thought the timer would wait ( stop the execution) and then once it finished, would go back to the app.handle

Comment: Ok. I tested the promise and wait in RunKit and it works.
The same code in google actions webhook doesn't work.

Comment: You definitely don't want to use an arbitrary timer to wait for a task to finish. Always serialize the tasks by waiting for them to finish.

Comment: The timer was just a test to see why my call was not waiting. Once I go this working with the right async, the real call to a database works fine now - waiting for the data. The actual call works with

Answer (score 0):

````
const app = conversation();


// wait ms milliseconds
function wait(ms) {
  console.log("in the wait");
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));
}
  
async function getData() {
          console.log(`start wait `);
          await wait(5000);
          console.log(`end wait `);
}

app.handle('findit', async conv => {
  console.log(`-----> handle activated `);
  console.log(`-----> BEFORE call getdata`); 
  getData();
  
  console.log(`--------END OF HANDLE ----------------------`);
 });

exports.ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);```

the issue was the conv was not async - the addition of the async to the app.handle('findit', async conv => { fixed the issue.
````